# Rename all files in directory to line present in each file using python

Tags: python, file, file-io, rename

I have a folder full of files in the following format:

```
temp0.txt

temp1.txt
temp3.txt
.
..
temp999.txt
...
```

The second line of each of these files contains the string I want to rename each file to respectively. To be clear, if "temp0.txt" contains "textfile0" in the second line, I want "temp0.txt" to be renamed to "textfile0.txt". Similarly, if "temp999.txt" contains "textfile123" in the second line, I want "temp999.txt" to be renamed to "textfile123.txt".

The following is what I have so far, but it doesn't work.

```
import os, linecache

for filename in os.listdir("."):
  with open(filename) as openfile:
    firstline = linecache.getline(openfile, 2)
  os.rename(filename, firstline.strip()+".txt")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The error I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename_ZINC.py", line 5, in <module>
    firstline = linecache.getline(openfile, 2)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.py", line 14, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.py", line 40, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/linecache.py", line 75, in updatecache
    if not filename or (filename.startswith('<') and filename.endswith('>')):
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. As pointed out "doesn't work" is pretty general and doesn't give us much information to go on... if you could give us more detail of the error message you got, what you tried to fix it and why that was unsuccessful, that would help us to help you.

Comment: Errors received added, my apologies for not including it earlier.

Comment: `linecache.getline` operates on a filename, not a file object.

Comment: @Felk Thank you for your help! Changing linecache.getline(openfile, 2) to linecache.getline(filename, 2) works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to tell you where you are going wrong.

`linecache` requires a filename as the first argument (as a string) , not the complete file obect. From [documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline)

> **linecache.getline(filename, lineno[, module_globals])**
>
> Get line lineno from **file named filename**. This function will never raise an exception — it will return '' on errors (the terminating newline character will be included for lines that are found).

So you should not open the file and then pass in the file object, instead you should have directly used the filename . Example -

```
for filename in os.listdir("."):
  secondline = linecache.getline(filename , 2)
  os.rename(filename, secondline.strip()+".txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the builtin `openfile.readline()` instead of linecache to get the necessary line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simpler method

```
import os,re

def changeName(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        line = next(f)
        secondline = next(f)
        if secondline == "textfile" + str(re.search(r'\d+', filename).group()): 
            #re.search() gets the first integer in the filename
            os.rename(filename, secondline + ".txt")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("Directory"):
    for file in files:
        file = os.path.join(root, file)
        changeName(file)
```

Comment: I get the following output, which I don't completely understand, but I've got my original script to work with one little change. Thank you for your help anyway.

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "rename.py", line 14, in <module>  
    changeName(file)  
  File "rename.py", line 7, in changeName  
    if secondline == "textfile" + str(re.search(r'\d+', filename).group()):   
NameError: global name 're' is not defined

Comment: sorry ,I forgot, you gotta import the re module like this `import re` :P rookie error

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll stick to my original edited code since it now works and I have to get this work done.